# htaccess add suffix to year. /wp-content/uploads/year-suffix/01/file.jpg

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Could you help me to rewrite urls?

Now urls looks like:

```
src="https://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/02/file1.png"
src="https://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/02/file2.png"
src="https://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/02/file3.png"
```

I'd like them to look like this:

```
src="https://example.com/wp-content/webp-uploads/2022/02/file1.webp"
src="https://example.com/wp-content/webp-uploads/2019/02/file2.webp"
src="https://example.com/wp-content/webp-uploads/2020/02/file3.webp"
```

I try something like this, but didn't work :C

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^wp-content/uploads/.+?\.(jpe?g|png|gif)$ /wp-content/webp-uploads/.+?\.webp$ [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

Unfortunately htaccess gives me a lot of trouble and I don't know how to write it :/

Comment: If you don't know how to write rewrite rules then I suggest you work through one or two of the many available tutorials and you take a look into the really good documentation of the rewriting module the apache http server uses.

Comment: You need to change how WordPress constructs these URLs - this isn't something you would do in `.htaccess` (unless these old URLs have been indexed in image search or linked to directly by 3rd parties).